# Spyder not showing complete documentation

Tags: python, python-3.5, spyder

I am trying to get documentation of some objects by pressing cmd+I in spyder but it gives a one line definition of the object instead of a detailed one. I am using python 3.5 and spyder 3.1.4. For e.g. documentation for OLS object looks like
[image]

where it should have been like
[image]

**Edit:** It doesn't happen with all of the class objects but intermittently with some not sure which ones. I currently have the following dependencies:

```
jedi >=0.9.0     :  0.9.0 (OK)
matplotlib >=1.0 :  2.0.0 (OK)
nbconvert >=4.0  :  4.2.0 (OK)
numpy >=1.7      :  1.11.3 (OK)
pandas >=0.13.1  :  0.19.2 (OK)
pep8 >=0.6       :  1.7.0 (OK)
psutil >=0.3     :  5.0.1 (OK)
pyflakes >=0.6.0 :  1.5.0 (OK)
pygments >=2.0   :  2.1.3 (OK)
pylint >=0.25    :  1.6.4 (OK)
qtconsole >=4.2.0:  4.3.0 (OK)
rope >=0.9.4     :  0.9.4-1 (OK)
sphinx >=0.6.6   :  1.5.1 (OK)
sympy >=0.7.3    :  1.0 (OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because OLS uses **doc** rather than the "triple quote" docstring ("""...""") for the class definition? Anytime it uses **doc**, trying to get the documentation from Cmd+I brings the problem.
For instance:

from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import OLS
OLS() # Cmd + I on this --> problem (OLS uses **doc**) 
OLS.score() # Cmd + I on this --> no problem (OLS.score uses triple quote docstring)
From the console OLS? brings the full documentation though. [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4792)